# /bin/sh -c not working with process builder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to run the following command via process builder:
ls -lrt my-directory | tail -1

I am using bin/sh -c when passing it in but cannot get it to work any way I try.(my custom directory depends on the function and is passed in as a string)

```
 process builder("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -lrt ", customDir, " | tail -1");
```

This gives the contents of the directory I am running the program out of. It's as if I simply typed ls (not even ls -lrt).

Both of

```
 String temp = "ls -lrt " + customDir + " | tail -1";
 process builder("/bin/sh ", "-c " temp);

 String temp = "ls -lrt " + customDir;
 process builder("/bin/sh ", "-c " temp, " | tail -1");
```

say that the directory doesn't exist even though I know it does. Removing /bin/sh -c simply gives me an error saying it couldn't understand the ls -lrt command which I understand. But I simply have no idea how to get it to produce the actual results I would get if I typed this command in seperately.

edit: the problem is not because of how I am calling process builder. I send the content to another function which calls process builder properly and relays its output.For simplicity, I just said process builder (...) in the examples.

Comment: For starters, you're missing a space. If customDir is `"foo"`, then `ls -lrt" + customDir` is `"ls -lrtfoo"`. Secondly, without the `-c` it makes sense that you get a "does not exist" error, because you tried to execute a script _named_ (not with the contents of) `"ls -lhtrcustomDir"`, which almost definitely doesn't exist on your computer.

Comment: My bad. I messed up when asking the question. I considered all those points when running it and have updated the question to show the format I used

Comment: `sh -c` only accepts 1 argument, but looking at the comma in your process builder, you are giving it multiple arguments

Comment: How do I pass in the command if it only accepts one argument? I tried combining the command as one and then passing it in (first ex in the block of two different ones) but it still didn't work